# Using Dates with the data.table package

Tags: r, datetime, data.table, plyr

I recently discovered the data.table package and was now wondering whether or not I should replace some of my plyr-code. To summarize, I really like plyr and I basically achieved everything I wanted. However, my code runs a while and the outlook of speeding things up was enough for me to run some tests. Those tests ended quite soon and here is the reason.

What I do quite often with plyr is to split my data by a column containing dates and do some calculations:

```
library(plyr)
DF <-  data.frame(Date=rep(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 60), each=6), y=c(rnorm(6, 1), rnorm(6, -1)))
#Split up data and apply arbitrary function
ddply(DF, .(Date), function(df){mean(df$y) - df[nrow(df), "y"]})
```

However, using a column with the Date-format does not seem to work in data.table:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(Date=rep(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 60), each=6), y=c(rnorm(6, 1), rnorm(6, -1)))
setkey(DT, Date)
#Error in setkey(DT, Date) : Column 'Date' cannot be auto converted to integer without losing information.
```

If I understand the package correctly, I only get substantial speed-ups when I use setkey(). Also, I think it wouldn't be good coding to constantly convert between Date and numeric. So am I missing something or is there just no easy way to achieve that with data.table?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] data.table_1.6.3 zoo_1.7-2        lubridate_0.2.5  ggplot2_0.8.9    proto_0.3-9.2    reshape_0.8.4   
[7] reshape2_1.1     xtable_1.5-6     plyr_1.5.2      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.0    lattice_0.19-30 stringr_0.5     tools_2.13.1
```

Comment: I haven't used data.table, but note that Sys.time() returns a `POSIXct` datetime value, not a `Date`. In particular, the value returned (the number of seconds elapsed since 1/1/1970) is in general not an integral value, so converting to an integer will indeed lose information as the error message says

Comment: Note that data.table can yield to quite substantial improvement in execution time even if you don't use `setkey`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
DT <- data.table(Date=as.ITime(rep(c(Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 60), each=6)),
                 y=c(rnorm(6, 1), rnorm(6, -1)))
setkey(DT, Date)
```

The data.table package contains some date/time classes with integer storage mode.
See `?IDateTime`:

> Date and time classes with integer storage for fast sorting and
>   grouping. Still experimental!

- `IDate` is a date class derived from `Date`. It has the same internal representation as the `Date` class, except the storage mode is integer.
- `ITime` is a time-of-day class stored as the integer number of seconds in the day. `as.ITime` does not allow days longer than 24 hours. Because `ITime` is stored in seconds, you can add it to a `POSIXct` object, but you should not add it to a `Date` object.
- `IDateTime` takes a date-time input and returns a data table with columns `date` and `time`.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I'm actually using lubridate, which in turn works great with ggplot2. Since all three packages (lubridate, ggplot2, plyr) are from the same author and work very well in combination, I guess I will stay with them a little longer instead of making the switch. But your answer gives a good workaround and when I have time I think I will play around and test the speed improvements with data.table. Thanks again!