# milliseconds timestamps as keys in data.table

Tags: r, datetime, data.table

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6978970/986817) the issue of using dates in `data.table`s was discussed. A solution is to use the built-in classes for time and dates. These work with a precision up to the second. Is there a work-around to handle milliseconds in indexed columns?

Comment: As I read that answer, regular data-time objects (with millisecond accuracy) can exist within data.table objects as long as you do not set them as keys. The IDates class is only needed if you want to key on them.

Comment: @DWin, I need to perform a rolling merge, so I need the data-time object to be indexable.

Comment: As always, a good question includes a complete specification of the problem and a sample dataset on which to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, data.table requires keys to be integers or similar (i.e. POSIXct rounded to seconds).  I would work-around this by storing 1000 * timestamp as your key, and perhaps having a separate column which is the non-rounded POSIXct.  Or you can convert to POSIXct on the fly whenever you need it.

Comment: Yes e.g. `as.integer(1000*as.numeric(format(Sys.time(),"%H%M%OS3")))`
`[1] 15017710`, as a work around. Having the date and time in two columns can be good when it comes to rolling joins: if you want the prevailing record within the same day but not from a previous day.

Answer (score 8):

The built-in class for Dates and Times, eg `POSIXct` works to milliseconds (windows) and microseconds (Linux, OS X).  You probably haven't turned on the option to have subseconds printed:

```
R> Sys.time()                            ## under default options
[1] "2011-10-25 17:40:05 CDT"
R> options("digits.secs"=7)              ## you may want this in ~/.Rprofile too
R> Sys.time()
[1] "2011-10-25 17:40:11.177271 CDT"     
R>
```